# How to pick specific parts of a Shape3D shape (processing)

Tags: java, processing

I am attempting to make a voxel-ish world builder, and I need to be able to stack the different blocks. How can I pick the separate sides of the block with the shapes3d library. Whenever I pick the shape, it renders it as the entire shape, and I am unsure of how to select only the part that I would like, so that I can build upon it.

```java
import peasy.*;
import shapes3d.*;
import shapes3d.utils.*;

Shape3D picked = null;
boolean clicked = true;

PeasyCam cam;

float[] xArr,yArr,zArr;
float x,y,z;
Box[] boxArr;
color[] colArr;
CameraState defaultState;

void setup(){

    size(1200,800,P3D);
    cam = new PeasyCam(this,width/2,height/2,0,500);
    cam.setMinimumDistance(200);
    cam.setMaximumDistance(2000);
    cam.setWheelScale(.05);
    cam.setDistance(1000);
    cam.rotateZ(PI/4);
    cam.rotateX(-PI/3);
    cam.setResetOnDoubleClick(false);
    defaultState = cam.getState();
    x=width/2;
    y=height/2;
    z=0;

    xArr = new float[200];
    yArr = new float[200];
    zArr = new float[200];
    colArr = new color[200];
    boxArr= new Box[200];

    for(int i=0;i<boxArr.length;i++){
        boxArr[i]=null;
    }

    xArr[0]=x;
    yArr[0]=y;
    zArr[0]=z;
    boxArr[0]=new Box(this);
    colArr[0]=color(255,255,255);
}

final float xrot=-PI/8,yrot=PI/4,zrot=0;
color col = color(255,255,255);
void mouseClicked(){
    clicked=true;
}

void draw(){
    pushMatrix();

    if (keyPressed&&key=='r'){
        cam.setState(defaultState);
        cam.setDistance(1000);
    }

    background(213, 243, 245);
    ambientLight(200,200,200);
    fill(col);
    lights();
    directionalLight(100,100,100,50,-50,0);

    int actuallength=0;
    for (int i=0;i<boxArr.length;i++){
        if(boxArr[i]!=null){
            actuallength++;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i<actuallength; i++){  
        boxArr[i].fill(colArr[i]);
        boxArr[i].strokeWeight(1.75);
        boxArr[i].stroke(155);
        boxArr[i].moveTo(xArr[i],yArr[i],zArr[i]);
        boxArr[i].drawMode(Shape3D.SOLID|Shape3D.WIRE);
        boxArr[i].draw();
    }

    if (clicked){
        clicked=false;
        picked = Shape3D.pickShape(this, mouseX, mouseY);

        int pos=0;
        for(int i=0;i<boxArr.length;i++){
            if(boxArr[i]==picked){
                pos=i;
            }
        }
        if(picked!=null){
            println();
            boxArr[actuallength]=new Box(this);
            xArr[actuallength]=xArr[pos]+(100);
            yArr[actuallength]=yArr[pos];
            zArr[actuallength]=zArr[pos];
            colArr[actuallength]=color(255,255,255);
        }
    }

    popMatrix();
}
```